# prolog How to get a permutaion of a list of a certain data structure .?

Tags: prolog

Can Anybody help me get all possible games not just what I achieved here which is only one combination ?

```
sched(0,[]).

sched(RoundNumber, [game(Y, RoundNumber, quarterfinals)|T]) :-
    RoundNumber > 1,
    Y is RoundNumber -1,
    N is RoundNumber -2,
    sched(N, T).
```

Comment: What did you type in for a query? Since you subtract `2` from `N` each recursive iteration, you'll get a number of games equal to your initial round number divided by 2.

Comment: permutation/2 will generate all, but I don't think will help you much

Comment: @mbratch  That is what I want because each game is between two players .

Comment: @CapelliC How Can I use permuation/2 in this predicate and why it won't help much ?? thanks

Comment: Could you give a simple example of a query and desired result?

Comment: ?- schedule_rounds(4,X).
X = [[game(1, 3, semi_finals), game(2, 4, semi_finals)], [game(1, 2, final)]] ;
X = [[game(1, 4, semi_finals), game(2, 3, semi_finals)], [game(1, 2, final)]] ;
false.

Answer (score 0):

@mbratch

?- schedule_rounds(4,X).

X = [[game(1, 3, semi_finals), game(2, 4, semi_finals)], [game(1, 2, final)]] ;

X = [[game(1, 4, semi_finals), game(2, 3, semi_finals)], [game(1, 2, final)]] ;
false.

?- schedule_rounds(8,X).

X = [[game(1, 5, quarter_finals), game(2, 6, quarter_finals), game(3, 7, quarter_finals),

game(4, 8, quarter_finals)], [game(1, 3, semi_finals), game(2, 4, semi_finals)],

[game(1, 2, final)]] ;

X = [[game(1, 5, quarter_finals), game(2, 6, quarter_finals), game(3, 7, quarter_finals),

game(4, 8, quarter_finals)], [game(1, 4, semi_finals), game(2, 3, semi_finals)],

[game(1, 2, final)]] ;

X = [[game(1, 5, quarter_finals), game(2, 6, quarter_finals), game(3, 8, quarter_finals),

game(4, 7, quarter_finals)], [game(1, 3, semi_finals), game(2, 4, semi_finals)],

[game(1, 2, final)]] ;

...